# Find $\lim_{n\to \infty}\mathbb{P}(N_{I}(n)=k)$ which is a random color point in interval

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

> Divide the interval $[0,1]$ into $n$ equal-sized subintervals. Suppose that each endpoint of the intervals is colored red with probability $p_n=\lambda/n$ independent. For any interval $I\subset [0,1]$(possibly open/clsed...), let $N_{I}(n)$ be the number of red points in $I$. Find 
>   $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\mathbb{P}(N_{I}(n)=k).$$
>   How about the $$Cov(N_{I}, N_{J}), \forall I\cap J\neq 0$$

Based on the idea of @user125932:

Fix $I$ which has the number of endpoints $m$, then
$$\mathbb{P}(N_{I}(n)=k| I)=\binom{m}{k}(\frac{\lambda}{n})^k(1-\frac{\lambda}{n})^{m-k}$$

$$\mathbb{P}(N_{I}(n)=k)=\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{P}(N_{I}(n)=k| I))=\mathbb{E}\bigg(\binom{m}{k}(\frac{\lambda}{n})^k(1-\frac{\lambda}{n})^{m-k}\bigg)$$

As $n\to\infty, m=n|I|:=n_{I}$, we have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}(N_{I}(n)=k)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}\bigg(\binom{n_{I}}{k}(\frac{\lambda}{n})^k(1-\frac{\lambda}{n})^{n_{I}-k}\bigg)=?[\mathbb{E}(\frac{\lambda^k e^{-\lambda}}{k!})=\frac{\lambda^k e^{-\lambda}}{k!}]$$
But how about the next step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $m_n$ be the number of points in $I$ when $[0,1]$ is divided into $n$ equal intervals. It can be shown that $m_n=\lfloor bn\rfloor - \lceil an\rceil$. As you said, 
$$
P(N_I(n)=k)=\binom{m_n}k(\lambda/n)^k (1-\lambda/n)^{m_n-k}\tag1
$$ 
Now, we have the approximation $\binom{m_n}k\sim \frac{m_n^k}{k!}$, in the sense that 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\binom{m_n}k}{\frac{m_n^k}{k!}}=1\tag2
$$
Can you prove this? In light of $(2)$, we can replace $\binom{m_n}{k}$ with $\frac{m_n^k}{k!}$ in $(1)$ without affecting the limit:
\begin{align}
P(N_I(n)=k)
&\sim \frac{m_n^k}{k!}(\lambda/n)^k(1-\lambda/n)^{m_n-k}\\
&=\left(\frac{m_n}n\right)^k\cdot \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}\cdot \left[\left(1-\frac{\lambda}n\right)^n\right]^{(m_n/n)}\cdot (1-\lambda/n)^{-k}
\end{align}
Now, we can simplify. We see the fraction $m_n/n$ appearing two places. It can be shown that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{m_n}n=b-a.$$
Furthermore, we have $\lim_n (1-\lambda/n)^n=e^{-\lambda}$ and $\lim_n (1-\lambda/n)^{-k}=1$. Making these replacements, we get
$$
\boxed{P(N_i(n)=k)\sim \frac{((b-a)\lambda)^k}{k!}\cdot e^{-(b-a)\lambda}.}
$$

Comment: (+1) Just some comments. Notice that this is saying that when $I = (a, b)$ we have $N_I$ is approximately a Poisson random variable with mean $(b-a) \lambda$. Also, about the covariance, we have that for disjoint intervals the processes are independent. Certainly this can be formalized as a limit of point processes.

Comment: So without the expectation to get $\mathbb{P}(N_{I}(n)=k)$?

Comment: @LoveQYG There is no reason to use expectation. $I$ is a fixed, deterministic interval, so $\mathbb E[\mathbb P(N_I(n)=k|I)]$ is just $P(N_I(n)=k)$.

Comment: @MikeEarnest I think $\mathbb{P}(B_{I}(n)=k|I)$ is the probability for fix $I$. But that is all right if apply expectation to $\mathbb{P}(B_{I}(n)=k|I)$.

Comment: @MikeEarnest How about the $\lim_{n\to \infty}\mathbb{P}(N_{I}(n)=k, N_{J}(n)=l)$

Comment: @MikeEarnest https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3365134/469065

Answer (score 0):

The strong law of large numbers shouldn't help here, since that requires that your variables $X_i$ each have the same fixed distribution independent of $n$, but here, the distribution of each $X_i$ depends on $n$.

A way forward: suppose there are $m$ endpoints in $I$. You can explicitly compute $\mathbb{P}(N_I(n) = k)$ in terms of $m, n, k, \lambda$ -- how many different ways can $k$ of the $m$ points be red? What is the probability of each such way? Then you can approximate $m$ in terms of $n$ (since intuitively, we should have $|I| \approx m/n$). This should allow you to find the limit as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: But in your way, $p_n$ is not useful. If let $Y$ be the number of endpoints in $I$. How to compute the conditional probability $\mathbb{P}(N_{I}(n)=k|Y=m)$?

Comment: Do you mean it is a binomial process?

Comment: Well, $p_n$ is just notation -- the expression I referred to above can be written in terms of $p_n$ instead of $\lambda$, but you might need to put it in terms of $\lambda$ to find the limit. Also note that for fixed $I$ and $n$, the set of endpoints in $I$ is fixed, so you don't need another random variable $Y = m$. And yes, for a fixed $n$, $N_I(n)$ has a binomial distribution, since as you alluded to above, it is a sum of independent Bernoulli variables (the $X_i$'s).

Comment: I have edited question that based your idea. But how about next? Thanks

Comment: So, the last step, where you say $m = n$ as $n \to \infty$, isn't quite right I think -- you should be able to approximate $m \approx n|I|$ (where $|I|$ is the length of $I$), in the sense that $|m - n|I||$ should be bounded by a constant (prove this!). Keep in mind that $I$ seems to be fixed in this problem, and your answer should depend on the given $I$.

Comment: But if let $m=n|I|$, how to compute the limit? It seems impossible.

Comment: It's not so different from what you've already done -- just go term by term: $\binom{m}{k} \to \frac{m^k}{k!} = \frac{n^k|I|^k}{k!}$, and $(1 - \lambda/n)^{n|I| - k} \to ((1 - \lambda/n)^n)^{|I|} \to e^{-\lambda |I|}$.

Comment: Do you mean $\forall \epsilon >0$ we have $|m-n|I||<\epsilon$?

Comment: No -- in fact you can show that $m-1 \leq n|I| \leq m+1$, which is sufficient for the purposes of the proof. Letting $s/n, t/n$ be the smallest and largest endpoints in $I$, we see that $[s/n, t/n] \subset I \subset [(s-1)/n, (t+1)/n]$, which implies the given inequality since $t - s = m-1$.

Comment: I also have a question about the joint law of $N_I, N_J$. What do you think about it? That is $\lim_{n\to \infty}\mathbb{P}(N_{I}(n)=k, N_{J}(n)=l).$ How to prove it exists?

Comment: Could you see this question? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3365134/469065